# Spring Boot: H2 database not saved to file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, h2

I'm trying to persist an H2 in-memory DB to a file with Spring Boot to reuse the data in there.

Unfortunately, the way to specify the datasource url like

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:file:~/WeatherDB;FILE_LOCK=FS
```

([complete application.properties](https://bitbucket.org/madmarkus/springbootexploring/src/f9941fc45b2d3d6578891ebb29924bc82ec9042d/src/main/resources/application.properties?at=master))

doesn't work for me. I can't find a file generated by H2 anywhere on my hard disk (also, saved data is not available after restarting the server).

To visualize this, I created a sample project that can be found on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/madmarkus/springbootexploring).

With that, it doesn't seem to make a difference if the application is run from an IDE with `gradle run` or after packaging it from the jar.

What config option is needed to persist and reuse the H2 DB ?

Update:

I realized there is a actuator endpoint for config options at `http://localhost:8080/configprops` that shows

```
"spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES": {

    "prefix": "spring.datasource",
    "properties": {
        "schema": null,
        "data": null,
        "xa": {
            "dataSourceClassName": null,
            "properties": { }
        },
        "separator": ";",
        "url": "jdbc:h2:file:~/WeatherDB",
        "platform": "all",
        "continueOnError": false,
        "jndiName": null,
        "sqlScriptEncoding": null,
        "password": "******",
        "driverClassName": "org.h2.Driver",
        "initialize": true,
        "username": "sa"
    }
},
```

But I just can't find an file `WeatherDB` on my harddisk nor is any data available after restarting the server.

Any suggestions very much welcome ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `application.properties` file is not being picked up.  Replace

```
compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.7.2.RELEASE"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.8.Final"
```

with

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. IMHO it should make a difference as the documentation says it would look in the classpath root if there is no application.config found in "a classpath /config package". (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Anyway, I gave it a try and it didn't work :(

Comment: You are right.  I compared your app with mine that works fine and found that you need to use Spring Boot JPA dependency instead of Spring Data JPA directly.  I have updated my answer to reflect this.  I have checked this change with your code and it works fine now.

Answer (score 12):

Table get dropped due to schema migration setting it to update solved for me.

```
application.properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: It works, thanks !
but where i can see this data stored ? in file ? or I can connect by SQL Developer to created database to watch it ?